# Scene change at MotionLayout

Tags: java, android

I have MotionLayout. And several scenes, for example 1, 3 and 4. How can I select them through the code, for example, switching during work?

```
app:layoutDescription="@xml/game_start_xml_colo_scene2"
```

```
       <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/Colo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chars_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/main_game_board"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/game_start_xml_colo_scene2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set them during inflation of the MotionLayout. This has been used to select a scene based on Landscape/Portrait available compute etc.

Once a MotionLayout is up (past onAttachToWindow) changing the MotionScene is not supported. (But it might be possible).

During onAttachToWindow MotionLayout builds out a state machine with a transition graphs and ConstraintSets, current Transtion, progress, clocks for timeCycles etc.
If the MotionSceen is simple enough it might be possible.

But you should not have to.
MotionScene can contain any number of Transitions and ConstraintSets.
ConstraintSets can be put in separate files(in 2.1).
You can programmatically add or mutate Transitions and ConstraintSets at runtime.

All that being said this is a feature that will be supported in 3.0.